# ERROR ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

We use the Django framework.

I ran the testapscheduler.py file to test how many TODO lists I have within the 30 minute deadline and whether I get a proper LINE notification, and I get the following error.

I believe I have the config set up correctly, so I don't know the cause of the error.

**ERROR**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

**testapscheduler.py**

```
import os
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings')

django.setup()

import logging
from models import Todo
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler, BlockingScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
import requests
from django.conf import settings

import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..'))


def notify_todo():
    # 現在の日時を取得
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))

    # 締め切りが30分以内のTODOリストを取得
    todos = Todo.objects.filter(
        deadline__gt=now - timedelta(minutes=30),
        deadline__lt=now + timedelta(minutes=30),
        ttime__isnull=False,
        ttime__gt=now.time()
    )

# 30分以内のTODOリストの数を出力
    # ログの出力名を設定
    logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')

    #ログレベルを設定
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    #ログをコンソール出力するための設定
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(sh)

    logger.debug(f'{len(todos)}個のTODOリストが締め切り30分以内にあります。')


    for todo in todos:
        #LINE NotifyのAPIトークンを取得
        api_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        
        # 通知メッセージの作成
        message = f"【{todo.title}】\n締切時間：{todo.deadline.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')}\n詳細：{todo.description}"

        # LINE Notifyに通知を送信
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_token}'}
        payload = {'message': message}
        requests.post('https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify', headers=headers, data=payload)


scheduler =BlockingScheduler(timezone='Asia/Tokyo')
scheduler.add_job(notify_todo, 'interval', seconds=2) # 2秒ごとに実行
scheduler.start()
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pip install config`?

Comment: @PApostol Thanks for the comment.

I tried pip install config and the following error came up next.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings'

Comment: Check that the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is set correctly. It should point to the `settings.py` file within the `config` module. You can check the current value of this variable by adding the line `print(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])` in your python script.

This should print the path to the `settings.py` file. If the variable is not set correctly, you can set it manually by adding the  line `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings'` to your Python script.

Again, adjust the path as necessary if the `settings.py` file is located elsewhere.

Comment: @SunderamDubey                            
①print(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])

②KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'　　　　　　

③if 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' not in os.environ:
     print("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is not set.")
else:
     print(os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'])
　　　　　　　　　
④"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable is not set.

⑤os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'config.settings'

⑥ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings'

Comment: @SunderamDubey        When I added the code in ① to testapscheduler.py and executed it, the error in ② occurred.
When I tried the code in ③ to check if Django was configured correctly or the environment variables were not set correctly, I got the answer in ④, so I changed the code in ⑤ to manually set the environment variables. When I entered it, an error of 6 occurred again.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the apscheduler settings?